# How do I convert float to byte[] by using logic

Tags: c#, arrays, floating-point

I need to convert `float` number to `byte[]` apart from using inbuilt method
`BitConverter.GetBytes`. I want to achieve this by using some logic.

Thank you.

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=BitConverter.GetBytes

Comment: What's wrong with `GetBytes`?  Do you want different output or are you just trying to replicate it?

Comment: Can we assume little or big endianness or do we need to try to determine that?

Comment: Nothing wrong with GetBytes, but I want to achieve it through logic.

Comment: What logic?  a float _is_ an array of bytes behind-the-scenes, so it's not clear at all what you want that's different than that.

Comment: @scotru : Sorry for missing on that info. It is little endianness.

Comment: There is no practical reason not to use `GetBytes`. It is far more likely to be correct and have good performance. The next person to read your code will immediately understand what `GetBytes` does; whereas they will have difficulty figuring out what your custom converter does. Writing your own version of standard functions is a staple of http://thedailywtf.com/

Comment: If this is from a file, Jon Skeet's misc library also includes code to read float from a binary reader including handling endianness: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/

Comment: If you are having issues with byte ordering then swap the bytes.

Comment: I want to convert float to Byte[] in Device Description language which is a very simple language and does not poses any inbuilt method to do so. So, my approach was to built this logic first in C# and then try to convert it to Device Description language.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, you can try `unsafe` in order just to scan `byte`s via `byte*` pointer:

```
public static byte[] GetFloatBytes(float value) {
  byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(float)];

  unsafe {
    // Let's treat a float as an array of bytes
    byte* b = (byte*) &value;

    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; ++i, ++b)
      result[i] = *b;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Test:

```
float x = (float) Math.PI;

// db 0f 49 40
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", BitConverter.GetBytes(x).Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))));
// db 0f 49 40
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", GetFloatBytes(x).Select(b => b.ToString("x2"))));
```

However, a better practice is to leave *pointers* to `BitConverter` and just call `BitConverter.GetBytes()`.

Comment: I want this logic to be implemented in Device Description Language which does not poses implementation of pointers. Can't we implement it avoiding pointers?